# Calling an Object's standard layout in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, page-layout, standardlayout

What I want to do is call the standard (Lightning) layout of an object to show in my Lightning component.  Let's assume the object I'm talking about is a custom object. And I created it with Lightning enabled in my org.  So when the custom object got created the Lightning standard layouts for that object also got created.

Just to be clear I DO NOT want to recreate the standard layout using the Lightning design system in my lightning component.

There's a way in Visualforce to call an object's standard view or edit layout I'm looking for the Lightning equivalent.

I'm familiar with the OOTB Record Detail Lightning component

I want to be able to do it dynamically. As in give me the record detail of Object B and then later I want the record detail of Object C where Object B and C are different custom objects.

Comment: where exactly are you planning on using this?  communities? Lex?

Comment: No not communities just in the org the lightning component is in.  The lightning component would be part of my Lightning app and I don't need it to work in the Lighting design system as a user dropable component.

Comment: I believe there is an OOTB REcord Detail component that you can drag and drop via the lightning app builder, and there should be an action button for creating a new record, which will pop up a modal with the fields you require upon creation

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with the Record Detail component but with that component you set what object the record detail refers to.  I want to be able to do it dynamically.  As in give me the record detail of Object B and then later I want the record detail of Object C where Object B and C are different custom objects.

Comment: unfortunately, that will require a custom component, and you will have to use SLDS with a ayout created by you =(

Comment: Lame, thanks! I figured since that was a feature in VF they'd have something like that in LC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific use case, there is no OOTB component that supports this (or at least that i know of).

That said, you will have to create your custom component in order to load your layout based on the objecttype selected.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid making my own layouts and use the out of the box ones.  It's part of a bigger use case. 
Thanks for the help!